# How to unit test derived ModuleBase class?

Tags: c#, discord.net

I would like to unit test one method in derived `ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>` class.

Is there a good way to hijack property [ModuleBase.Context](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.Commands.ModuleBase-1.html#Discord_Commands_ModuleBase_1_Context)?

One option might be overriding it to `auto-property` and assign it with fake instance of derived `SocketCommandContext` class. The same thing might be needed for `SocketCommandContext.User` member.

Perhaps there is better way.

[I couldn't find anything useful in project page](https://github.com/discord-net/Discord.Net/tree/dev/test)

Thanks.

```cs
public class SampleModule: ModuleBase<SocketCommandContext>
    {
        private readonly IRepository _repository;

        public SocketCommandContext Context { get; set; }

        public SampleModule(
            IRepository _repository)
        {
            _repository= repository;
        }

        [Command("test", RunMode = RunMode.Async)]
        public async Task RunAsync([Summary("user")]SocketGuildUser? targetUser = null)
        {
            var user = targetUser ?? Context.User as SocketGuildUser ?? throw new Exception();
            var result = await _repository.GetAsync(user.Id);
            await ReplyAsync(result.Value);
        }
}
```

```cs
private readonly Mock<IRepository> _repositoryMock = new(MockBehavior.Strict);

 [TestMethod]
 public async Task Should_Reply()
 {
      _repositoryMock
          .Setup(pr => pr.GetAsync(It.IsAny<ulong>()))
          .Verifiable();

     

     var module = new SampleModule(_repositoryMock.Object);
     await module.RunAsync();

     _repositoryMock.Verify();
 }
```

Comment: You shouldn't be unit testing the command itself, but rather the components it uses. DNet isn't very test friendly and it probably not gonna be worth the effort needed to make all the necessary abstractions. If your commands utilize services, you can make sure those service classes are testable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to mock `ModuleBase.Context` by invoking via reflection internal method `IModuleBase.SetContext(ICommandContext)` with assigns new context from parameter.

```
private void SetContext(SampleModule module)
{
    var setContext = module.GetType().GetMethod(
        "Discord.Commands.IModuleBase.SetContext",
        BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
    setContext.Invoke(_module, new object[] { _commandContextMock.Object });
}
```

As for `SocketGuildUser`, one can use internal `ctor` which requires `SocketGuild` and `SocketGlobalUser`. They also need to be instantiated with reflection and need other dependencies.

`SocketGlobalUser` was a tough one as the class definition is even internal.

Another option is to switch `Socket*` types to interfaces which they implement.

Like `SocketGuildUser` would become `IGuildUser` or `IUser`.

**Example methods which instantiate Socket types**

```
    public static object CreateSocketGlobalUser(DiscordSocketClient discordSocketClient, ulong id)
        {
            var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
            var discordNetAssembly = assemblies
                .FirstOrDefault(pr => pr.FullName == "Discord.Net.WebSocket, Version=2.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null");

            var socketGlobalUserType = discordNetAssembly.GetType("Discord.WebSocket.SocketGlobalUser");


            var socketGlobalUserCtor = socketGlobalUserType.GetConstructor(
                BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance,
                null, new[]{
                        typeof(DiscordSocketClient),
                        typeof(ulong),
                    }, null);

            var parameters = new object[] {
                discordSocketClient, id
            };

            var socketGlobalUser = socketGlobalUserCtor.Invoke(parameters);
            return socketGlobalUser;
        }

public static SocketGuild CreateSocketGuild(DiscordSocketClient discordSocketClient, ulong id)
        {
            var bindingAttr = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
            var socketGuildCtor = typeof(SocketGuild).GetConstructor(
             bindingAttr,
             null, new[]{
                    typeof(DiscordSocketClient),
                    typeof(ulong),
             }, null);

            var socketGuild = (SocketGuild)socketGuildCtor.Invoke(new object[] {
                discordSocketClient, id,
            });
            return socketGuild;
        }

public static SocketGuildUser CreateSocketGuildUser(SocketGuild socketGuild, object socketGlobalUser)
        {
            var bindingAttr = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
            var types = new[]{
                typeof(SocketGuild),
                socketGlobalUser.GetType(),
            };
            var socketGuildUserCtor = typeof(SocketGuildUser).GetConstructor(
               bindingAttr,
               null, types, null);

            var parameters = new object[] {
                socketGuild, socketGlobalUser
            };

            var socketGuildUser = (SocketGuildUser)socketGuildUserCtor.Invoke(parameters);

            return socketGuildUser;
        }
```

`ReplyAsync` method internally calls `Context.Channel.SendMessageAsync` and with a bit of work it can also be mocked.

```
private readonly Mock<ICommandContext> _commandContextMock = new(MockBehavior.Strict);
private readonly Mock<IMessageChannel> _messageChannelMock = new(MockBehavior.Strict);
private readonly Mock<IUserMessage> _userMessageMock = new(MockBehavior.Strict);

_commandContextMock
    .Setup(pr => pr.Channel)
    .Returns(_messageChannelMock.Object);

_messageChannelMock
    .Setup(pr => pr.SendMessageAsync(
        It.IsAny<string>(),
        It.IsAny<bool>(),
        It.IsAny<Embed>(),
        It.IsAny<RequestOptions>(),
        It.IsAny<AllowedMentions>(),
        It.IsAny<MessageReference>()))
    .ReturnsAsync(_userMessageMock.Object);
```

**The example test with things above.**

```
private readonly Mock<ICommandContext> _commandContextMock = new(MockBehavior.Strict);
private readonly Mock<IMessageChannel> _messageChannelMock = new(MockBehavior.Strict);
private readonly Mock<IUserMessage> _userMessageMock = new(MockBehavior.Strict);
private readonly Mock<IRepository> _repositoryMock = new(MockBehavior.Strict);

 [TestMethod]
 public async Task Should_Reply()
 {
      _repositoryMock
          .Setup(pr => pr.GetAsync(It.IsAny<ulong>()))
          .Verifiable(); 

      var discordSocketClientMock = new Mock<DiscordSocketClient>(MockBehavior.Strict);
      var socketGlobalUser = CreateSocketGlobalUser(discordSocketClientMock.Object, 1);
      var socketGuild = CreateSocketGuild(discordSocketClientMock.Object, 1);
      var socketGuildUser = CreateSocketGuildUser(socketGuild, socketGlobalUser);

      _commandContextMock
          .Setup(pr => pr.Channel)
          .Returns(_messageChannelMock.Object);

      _commandContextMock
          .Setup(pr => pr.User)
          .Returns(socketGuildUser);

      _messageChannelMock
          .Setup(pr => pr.SendMessageAsync(
              It.IsAny<string>(),
              It.IsAny<bool>(),
              It.IsAny<Embed>(),
              It.IsAny<RequestOptions>(),
              It.IsAny<AllowedMentions>(),
              It.IsAny<MessageReference>()))
          .ReturnsAsync(_userMessageMock.Object);

     var module = new SampleModule(_repositoryMock.Object);
     SetContext(_commandContextMock.Object);


     await module.RunAsync();

     _repositoryMock.Verify();
 }
```

Some parts could be extracted to test base class given by how big the setup code is.